# Where did cvs-mirror.mozilla.org go?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to build Firefox 3.0.5 (yes, I know, an antique) on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7 (64-bit) and the build process has me thoroughly confused. The current Mozilla Developer help pages have no accessible history so it's impossible to read the versions pertinent to my quandary. For instance, mach and Mercurial are not germane. I've recovered my target options using about:buildconfig on a running installation of Firefox 3.0.5 (running on a 32-bit RHEL 5.3 system), and now I'm trying to use 'make -f client.mk' after writing my own mozconfig file.

But one of the very first things 'make -f client.mk' tries to do is run cvs (which I had to install) and reach cvs-mirror.mozilla.org...which doesn't exist anymore. How do I circumvent this? More generally, how do I get all of the about:buildconfig into mozconfig? (the configure options went into ac_add_options instructions, fine, but what of the gcc options?)

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/it/2015/07/28/vcs-decom-status/ "CVS & BZR services decommissioned on mozilla.org" as of 28 July 2015